# Can i Load saved games of a Steam Skyrim to a non-steam Skyrim ?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that I can share/pass saves of Skyrim between computers, but can I share/pass saves of Skyrim between computers when one has Skyrim through Steam and the other does not?

Comment: Skyrim can only be purchased and played through Steam. Any attempt to circumvent Steam suggests piracy, which we take a zero tolerance approach to here at Arqade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is yes, since having steam does not affect any game "saving format".
Just make sure you are transfering the save of Skyrim,and not the one that steam saves and sync to cloud.